# Taking quartile values of an list of list, and plotting them

Tags: python, list, numpy, ode

My code below, when ran, plots 100 curves on a plot for random values of a parameter in an ODE system. However, I am trying to take a 'cross section' of every time point, so I'd have all 100 values at that point, and then take the upper and lower quartiles and median of those values (which in the code would be an array or list), and plot those:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

N = 1000
I0, R0 = 1, 0
S0 = N - I0 - R0
J0 = I0
beta, gamma = 2/7, 1/7
t = np.linspace(0, 100,100)

empty = []
for i in range(100):
    empty.append(random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)*gamma)

def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma):
    S, I, R, J = y
    dS = ((-beta * S * I) / N)
    dI = ((beta * S * I) / N) - (gamma * I)
    dR = (gamma * I)
    dJ = ((beta * S * I) / N)
    return dS, dI, dR, dJ

solns =  []
for empt in empty:
    ces = odeint(deriv, (S0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, empt, gamma))
    solns.append(ces)

J_diffs = []
for sol in solns:
    S, I, R, J = sol.T
    J_diffs.append(np.diff(J))

fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
ax.set_xlabel('Time in days')
ax.set_ylabel('Number')
ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
xcoords = [2.5, 97.5]
for J_diff in J_diffs:
    ax.plot(t[1:], J_diff, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2)
```

What I have tried, is using:

```
for val in solns:
    ax.plot(t[1:], np.percentile(val,25), 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2)
```

but this is an error for dimensions as it only retrieves 1 value in solns, not all of  them.
I then tried

```
for t in solns:
    ax.plot(t[1:], np.percentile(val,25), 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2)
```

as I thought it makes more sense to select the timepoints corresponding to each value, but this returns the same error. I believe I am missing the logical approach on how to achieve this. The end result is to have 3 curves, one displaying a curve made of the 97.5 percentile of all values, one for the 2.5, and one for 0.5th. Where Have I gone wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the percentiles first, then plot them. Use something like this:

```
def plot_percentile(data, percentile):
    percentiles = [np.percentile(val, percentile) for val in data]
    ax.plot(t, percentiles, 'blue', alpha=1, lw=2)

plot_percentile(solns, 97.5)
plot_percentile(solns, 2.5)
plot_percentile(solns, 0.5)
```

This code put all three curves on one graph, which isn't what you wanted, but I think you could adapt it from here (use subplots, and pass the subplot index to `plot_percentile()` as an argument or something similar).

Comment: Must I assign `data` to a previous variable?

Comment: I'm not sure which variable you're referring to. You can change any of the variable names in plot_percentile, though. It doesn't even need to be within a function. My code is just an example of how you could approach it

Comment: I understand, though Im confused what 'data' represents, as this code doesnt produce any output when run

Comment: Sorry, this should be appended to the bottom of your first code block. Data is just your list of randomly generated lists (e.g. I called it with `solns`).